# fix for unhiding column in Excel has stopped working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have just moved to Windows 10 and Excel 2016 (from Excel 2000) and found that CTRL-SHIFT-0 no longer works to unhide columns, because it's been hijacked by a language setting (for hotkeys for changing keyboard layout). I followed the instructions I found on this site and changed this setting to Not Assigned, which fixed it and gave me back my Excel keystroke shortcut.

My problem is that now, 2 days later, it has stopped working again, though the language setting is still Not Assigned.

I am wondering if there is something *else* interfering with CTRL-SHIFT-0 that is still trumping the Excel use of this shortcut.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the keyboard shortcut to Unhide a column in Excel 2010?](http://superuser.com/questions/183197/whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-a-column-in-excel-2010)

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Windows 10 and Excel 2016. My question is not a duplicate of the one you suggest - I used that fix and it worked, then stopped working again, even though I had not made any further changes to (any) settings. Was hoping to avoid having to set up a macro given that the fix did work, even if only temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

> I also had the same problem. It wouldn't work even though I had unassigned  the hotkeys to changing the keyboard layout. 
>   So I deleted the second keyboard layout and then it worked.

I had a similar experience but didn't have a second keyboard layout to delete so I add a keyboard layout and then deleted it. Now the unhide columns in Excel 2010 works again. Yay!

Edit - next day
It seems that the fix is not persistent between boots. Crtl-0 works ok (hide column) but Ctrl-Shift-0 (unhide) does not. Adding or removing a language seems to bring back ctrl-shift-0 functionality, but you need to do that at every boot.

Perhaps something else is intercepting ctrl-shift-0 and altering languages gives control back to the language bar which then passes it onto excel?

Comment: I am happy to advise that the unhide column keyboard shortcut has been fixed with the April 2018 Windows Update. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro and then connect that to a button on your ribbon, because the buttons in your ribbon automatically have a hotkey connected to them. You could use the following code for unhiding all columns.

```
Sub UnhideAllColumns()
' unhide all columns on the current worksheet

Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It woudln't work even though I had unassigned the hotkeys to changing the keyboard layout.
So I deleted the second keyboard layout and then it worked.