# Excel 2010: Hiding column with Ctrl+0 does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

it is strange ... every shortcut overview I found so far claims that Ctrl+0 is meant to hide the selected column. On my computer (German Windows 7, German Windows 10, German keyboard layout) the shortcut does nothing.

It is not a matter of language settings as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/183197/whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-a-column-in-excel-2010).

Comment: Good problem to solve. +1 for good question

Answer (score 1):

Oh well ... I don't know whether this will work on all computers, but on mines the column can be hidden with **`Ctrl + 8`** ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/522799)

Comment: I thought it would be nice to share my found solution to the problem.

Comment: @Vince42 - You are welcome to do that once you have earned the privilege to submit comments to questions and answers other then your own.